# installing MySQL 64 bit community edition on linux production server from an newbie

Tags: mysql, linux, 64-bit, centos, debian

Currently i am having command **sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server**

I don't know whether it's going to install 32 bit or 64 bit mysql.

Currently i am looking command for installing MySQL 64 bit edition on

1) debian 64 bit and

2) centos 64 bit

for production purpose.

Comment: It probably will install a 64 bits server, because the distribution is 64 bits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS:
`yum install mysql-server`

Debian: `apt-get install mysql-server`

In general, it will pull the same packages as your installed architecture, unless it specifically has other architecture dependencies (multilib in Archlinux).